# PGI equivalent of "use ifcore" with Intel compilers

Tags: fortran, libraries, intel, pgi

I am currently working on compiling a model with PGI, originally designed for Intel compilers.  One of the scripts uses `use ifcore` which is an Intel-specific command that links in miscellaneous run-time libraries.  I am having trouble finding the PGI equivalent (for a linux machine)...any ideas?

I was looking at `dflib` but that appears to be windows-specific.
I am using mpif90 to compile the model currently.

Comment: There may not be a whole replacement for that module, so do you know which particular entities from `ifcore` you use?

Comment: I don't know the particular entities used.  "use ifcore" is in a subroutine of a script that sends information to several other scripts.

This is my first time doing anything with compilers so I'm not very knowledgeable on how everything is split up.

Comment: I made the same suggestion to a similar question (different ifort module), but you could perhaps remove the `use ifcore` line and see what complaints come about during compiling/linking.

Comment: When I remove `use ifcore`, I start getting errors for the source line: _PGF90-S-0285-Source line too long_.  But since I don't know much about `ifcore`, I don't know that the error necessarily related directly to that.

Comment: It isn't related.  It's probably just that as soon as the compiler came across a module it couldn't find it aborted compilation (so didn't complain about the other errors).  [There'll surely be an option to allow longer lines, but I'm not familiar with that compiler any longer.]

Comment: I have been digging into the code a bit more and I have found that this particular subroutine uses `call tracebackqq` which is the traceback library under `ifcore`.

Comment: The pgfortran option to extend line lengths is `-Mextend`, although PGI frustratingly only allows line lengths up to 132.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ross! :)  Unfortunately I still get the same error using `-Mextend`

Comment: I would just comment out the call to `tracebackqq`. Also, it's quite likely you will have to break lines manually where they are too long. If macros are involved, it could be tricky.

Comment: -Mextend extends F77's 72 column limit to extend up to 132 columns.  F90 limits lines to 132 columns.  You typically can get longer than that, but it's not unlimited and better to stick to being standard compliant.  Hence, it's best to add continuation characters to split the long line into multiple lines.

Comment: From Intel's docs, it looks like tracebackqq simply dumps a trace back on error.  The PGI flag "-traceback" flag is on by default so if the program does crash, you can produce a trace back by setting the environment variable "PGI_TERM=trace".  Hence, you should be able to remove the call to tracebackqq.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Mat!  Since this is my first time directly working with compilers, it's been difficult for me to explain some of the changes I have made, so thank you for saying that in English for me haha.